# My Implementation of Midpoint Displacement to generate islands does not create the desired pattern?

Tags: processing, terrain, heightmap

I wanted to create an effect such as the one in [this article](http://www.contralogic.com/procedural-island-generator/), starting from the code found at the processing port of 'realistic terrain in 130 lines'. I modified the code so it only produces a grey scale height map in Processing rather than a 3D terrain. However, my code does not produce island heightmaps and also leaves an unusual square pattern, as pictured [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QJS2.png).

My Code is as follows:

```
int size = 512;

Terrain t;

float rough = 0.7;
void setup() {

  t = new Terrain(8, size);
  doit();
}

void doit() {

  t.generate(rough);
  size(513, 513);
  loadPixels();
  for (int a=0;a<t.tMap.length;a++) {
    float val = ((t.tMap[a]+24)/48)*255;
    pixels[a] = color(floor(val));
  }
  updatePixels();
}

void mousePressed() {
  doit();
}

class Terrain {
  public final int tSize, tMax;
  public float[] tMap;
  public float tRoughness;

  Terrain(int detail, int size) {
    tSize  = size+1;
    tMax = tSize-1; 
    tMap = new float[tSize*tSize];
  }

  private float getp(int x, int y) {
    if (x < 0) x= tMax + x;
    if (x > tMax) x= x % tMax;
    if (y < 0) y= tMax + y;
    if (y > tMax) y= y % tMax;

    return tMap[x + tSize * y];
  }

  private void setp(int x, int y, float val) {

    tMap[x + tSize * y] = val;
  }

  public void generate(float roughness) {
    tRoughness = roughness;  
    //set edges and corners 0
    for (int x=0;x<tSize;x++) {
      setp(x, 0, 0);
      setp(x, tMax, 0);
    }
    for (int y=0;y<tSize;y++) {
      setp(y, 0, 0);
      setp(y, tMax, 0);
    }
    //seed random numbers every 16
    for (int x=0;x<tSize;x+=16) {
      for (int y=0;y<tSize;y+=16) {
        setp(x, y, random(-(roughness*16), roughness*16));
      }
    }
    //divide each 16x16 square
    for (int x=0;x<tSize;x+=16) {
      for (int y=0;y<tSize;y+=16) {
        divide(16, x, y);
      }
    }
  }

  private void divide(int size, int smallestX, int smallestY) {
    int x, y, half = size/2;
    float scale = tRoughness * size;
    if (half < 1) return;

    for (y = smallestY + half; y < tMax; y += size) {
      for (x = smallestX + half; x < tMax; x += size) {
        square(x, y, half, random(-scale, scale));
      }
    }
    for (y = smallestY; y <= tMax; y += half) {
      for (x = (y + half + smallestY) % size; x <= tMax; x += size) {
        diamond(x, y, half, random(-scale, scale));
      }
    }
    divide(size/2, smallestX, smallestY);
  }

  private float average(float[] values) {
    int valid = 0;
    float total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i] != -1) {
        valid++;
        total += values[i];
      }
    }
    return valid == 0 ? 0 : total / valid;
  }

  private void square(int x, int y, int size, float offset) {
    float ave = average(new float[] {
      getp(x - size, y - size), // upper left
      getp(x + size, y - size), // upper right
      getp(x + size, y + size), // lower right
      getp(x - size, y + size)  // lower left
    }
    );
    setp(x, y, ave + offset);
  }

  private void diamond(int x, int y, int size, float offset) {
    float ave = average(new float[] {
      getp(x, y - size), // top
      getp(x + size, y), // right
      getp(x, y + size), // bottom
      getp(x - size, y)  // left
    }
    );
    setp(x, y, ave + offset);
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You break down the terrain in 16x16 blocks first. In the output, these borders are quite visible. Why is that? Well, because the values at the border differs a lot more than the values within each block differ.

The differences between blocks are determined by the initial `generate` values, the differences with a block are caused by `divide`. You need more variation in `generate` or less in `divide`.

Even then it might be worthwhile to apply a smoothing operator over the whole image after all blocks have been generated. This decreases roughness a bit, but it will further decrease the visibility of specific borders (especially to the human eye; a statistical test is still likely to prove that the image was generated by an axis-aligned process)

Comment: That helps quite a bit, Thanks!